# How to start Xcode4 opengl project for mac

Tags: opengl, xcode4

Good Day

I want to start a opengl project, mainly to follow the Nehe tutorials.

My problem is that I only see templates for opengl es for iphone, and when I click build on those, I only have the choice between iphone or ipad simulator.

So How can I get started with a simple opengl template to follow the tutorial series, without using a simulator, but executing it natively on my mac osx lion?

Please give me a step by step instruction if possible :)

I looked around everywhere but all I found were instructions for Xcode 3 and below etc.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a normal Cocoa project, add the OpenGL framework. In your main window add a NSOpenGLView.

http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/resources/opengl/

Answer (score 1):

I am currently in the process of writing an intuitive Xcode 4 Template for an OpenGL Mac application, which I think is exactly what you were wanting.

In the mean time, you can look at [this](https://github.com/mk12/Pong-Ultimate), a Pong clone I made in OpenGL on the Mac, done the proper way.

EDIT: The template isn't completely finished, but it's definately usable. I didn't implemenet the 3D option, so picking that in the dropdown will result in blank files.

Donwload it from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2742457/OpenGL%20Application.xctemplate.zip) and then move it into the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Applications folder in your user director.

Comment: That would be nice to have a template.  Will you post a link here when you are done?